# I want to send push notification in quickblox catting application

Tags: java, android

I am developing a real time chatting application in which i use QuickBlox demo. When user one and user tow both r on-line it works fine but when one user is of-line and some one sending a message to this user(of-line) user he doesn't get any message or notification when he come back on-line. 
Can any one suggests me how to sent push notification in quickblox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should learn this carefully it defiantly work.

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android